# How is shutdown.exe unclosable (under Windows XP)?

Tags: windows, shutdown

How does the Windows program `shutdown.exe` make itself unclosable, even from Task Manager, but how does `shutdown /a` terminate it?
From the disassembly, it looks like it may be built into the kernel, but I'm unsure. I am **not** going to use it to write malware.

Comment: Perhaps it's not uncloseable, but the restriction is built in to Task Manager? I can't test right now, but from memory, Task Manager refuses to kill certain system processes, even though they can be killed by Process Explorer or through Windows API calls.

Comment: The `shutdown.exe` process normally exits immediately, so it is certainly not unclosable.  Do you mean the window that Windows pops up to warn you about the impending shutdown?

Comment: @harryjohnston, I mean the window that cannot be closed

Comment: @user2229828: can you show us a screenshot, or at least tell us what the window text is?

Comment: @harryjohnston, you can run `shutdown -s` on Windows via run, and see for yourself, just save anything you haven't saved, it will shut down your computer, and the window it creates is unclosable, unless you run `shutdown -a`

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't do that.  Anyway, in the absence of a description, I can only guess that you're talking about the dialog that Windows XP (*not* `shutdown.exe`) generates to warn about an impending timed shutdown.  This dialog is generated by the operating system, not by a process running in the user's context, which is why you can't use Task Manager to close it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I guess you're right, I don't have Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program `shutdown.exe` does not make itself uncloseable, in fact it normally exits immediately.  The window you're talking about is generated by the operating system itself to warn the user that a system shutdown is pending.  (In more recent versions of Windows this warning is presented differently.)  You can get the same effect in your own code by calling [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Similarly, `shutdown /a` doesn't terminate the window, it just calls [`AbortSystemShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to cancel the shutdown.  Windows then removes the warning window since it is no longer applicable.

If you were to figure out which process is actually generating the window, you could no doubt terminate that process, assuming you have admin access.  On the other hand if it is one of the system critical processes then terminating it will crash the system.